# Images not loading on mobile view

Tags: magento2, product, image, mobile

I am using magento 2.3.2. My product images are not loading on mobile. Please help.It a critical issue. Its just shows infinite loading and then hang ups. This happens on product view page.

Comment: any error showing in console ?

Comment: @ShafeelSha  No...........

Comment: @Nafisa, please try increasing the value of memory_limit in your server's php.ini file. Also in the Magento backend, make sure you set the scope to Global for small_image , thumbnail and base_image attributes. After setting it to global, delete the generated folder and cache folders. Run the di compile and static content deploy commands.

Comment: @MGento.... Thax i will try this. There is an another issue on desktop, my product page gets freezes and nothing happens, not able to add to cart. see https://ihouzit.com/shop-products/bedroom/bediide-table-with-mango-wood-structure-front-part-with-reclaimed-wood-details-metal-legs.html

Comment: I can see JS errors in console. The first one is mageplazaSearchProducts is not defined and another one Unexpected token a in JSON at position 155. These could be the reason the page is not  getting loaded. To confirm this, try disabling the module which access this vairable